# How to use json schema to validate the special dependency?

Tags: json

In the following `JSON` example, I'd like to make sure the value of `"B"` is one of the `"name"` of array `A`'s items, could this be possible?
In my opinion, oneOf, dependencies, foreignkey all cannot satisfy this situation.

```
{
    "A": [
        {"name": "a1"},
        {"name": "a2"},
        {"name": "a3"}
    ],

    "B": "xxx" // xxx is one of the "name" of array A's items
}
```

Comment: Hey, do _not_ use punctuations like `”` and `“` in programming.

Comment: Could I ask why pls? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Simple reason: they're not recognized. Usually only character `"` (0x22 in ASCII) and `'` (0x27 in ASCII) are supported/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Schema:

```
{
  "definitions" : {
    "name" : {
      "oneOf" : [
        { 
          "type" : "string",
          "pattern" : "^a1$"
        },
        { 
          "type" : "string",
          "pattern" : "^a2$"
        },
        { 
          "type" : "string",
          "pattern" : "^a3$"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  "properties" : {
    "A" : {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/name"
    },
    "B" : {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/name"
    }
  }
}
```

Valid instance:

```
{
  "A" : "a1",
  "B" : "a2"
}
```

Not valid instance:

```
{
  "A" : "a1",
  "B" : "b"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. But I'm afraid that it's not what I want. I'd like something like foreign-key in database.

Comment: No problem. I think I actually answered your question as phrased above. Perhaps consider re-phrasing with very concrete requirements?